# MVC controller Bulk Message Module Clone issues

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Message Controller.

I have a application users.

So ı have a bulkmessage send module many users, after have selected and sending message for users

panel has been dropdown user list + message body textbox

How many users were selected so sending a message.

**Problem**
We have A,B,C,D,E users İf ı can choosen 8 user and body write sending

the same message being cloned A user has been 8 message clone or B user has been 8 message clone. Sending messages by the number of Choose users.

```
private void SendMessage(string chatMsg, string Subject, int CUserId, ApplicationUser[] AllUsers, string item)
{
    if (item != "")
    {
        var Usr = AllUsers.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Username == item.Trim()).Id;

        int Groupid = 0;

        bool result = false;

        var QueryGetGroup = db.Database.SqlQuery<DtoGrouping>("select COUNT( ChatGroupId ) as GroupCount ,ChatGroupId from ChatGroupUser where ChatUserId in(" + CUserId + "," + Usr + ") group by ChatGroupId");

        if (QueryGetGroup != null)
        {
            foreach (var item1 in QueryGetGroup)
            {
                if (item1.GroupCount > 1)
                {
                    result = true;
                    Groupid = item1.ChatGroupId;
                }
            }
        }


        if (result == true)
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            //
            string sqlCreateGroup = "declare @GroupId int=null \n ";
            sqlCreateGroup += "insert into ChatGroup(GroupCreatorBy,IsActive,GroupName) values(" + CUserId + ",1,'" + Subject + "') set @GroupId=SCOPE_IDENTITY() \n ";
            sqlCreateGroup += "insert into ChatGroupUser (ChatUserId,ChatGroupId) values(" + CUserId + ",@GroupId) \n ";
            sqlCreateGroup += "insert into ChatGroupUser (ChatUserId,ChatGroupId) values(" + Usr + ",@GroupId) \n ";
            sqlCreateGroup += "select @GroupId \n ";

            var getgroupid = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sqlCreateGroup).FirstOrDefault();

            Groupid = Convert.ToInt32(getgroupid.ToString());
        }


        Guid messageId = System.Guid.NewGuid();

        ChatMessage con = new ChatMessage();
        con.Msg = chatMsg;
        con.ConnectionIDUser = messageId.ToString();
        con.SendDate = DateTime.Now;
        con.SendFrom = CUserId;
        con.ChatGroupId = Groupid;
        con.IsDeleted = false;
        //con.ImageFile=null //now not working
        con.IsSeen = false;
        db.ChatMessages.Add(con);

        db.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

Comment: Oke i can do it